# how to delete by value in angular 6 and firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angular6

Suppose I have a query in Mysql i.e.: " delete from table where counter= 3 "

what will be the query in angular 6 and firebase realtime database?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
deleteUser(count){
  return this.db.collection('users',ref => ref.where('count', '=', count)).delete();
}
```

You can get the collection and delete its entity doc using key/id.

Comment: where is condition? such as - " where counter= 3". I want to delete where counter value is 3

Comment: I have updated my answer please use **ref => ref.where('count', '=', count)** as where condition.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: ref.where is not a function
I'm using firebase realtime database

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/angular/angularfire/ this package?

Comment: am using 'angularfire2/database'

Comment: import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {}

afs.collection.('items', ref => ref.where('count', '==', count))

Try above code it must solve your problem.

Comment: It's realtime database, can't use filestore